# How to disable the built-in DHCP from macOS network sharing

Tags: macos, iphone, network, sharing

I connect my iPhone to macOS to make macOS use iPhone's network.

Then I connect a USB network adapter to macOS, setting macOS to share the network from "iPhone USB" to the USB network adapter.

The network adapter is connected to a standalone device acting as router, which runs OpenWrt.

macOS sets up a network 192.168.2.0/24 and every device that connects to OpenWrt would get DHCP lease with gateway 192.168.2.1, which is the macOS system.

I need to disable this DHCP service from macOS, and make all devices connected to OpenWrt to get DHCP lease from it, especially, the DNS and gateway should be 192.168.2.11.

Another question is, how to change the subnet from 192.168.2.0/24 to 192.168.249.0/24?

Thanks.

[image: iPhone USB network tether]

[image: macOS sharing network on USB Ethernet/LAN]

Comment: I don't think you can turn that off on the Mac. I think the way to approach this would be to configure the Router in a way where the Mac acts as the WAN and handles DHCP for its clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [in this Apple Discussion post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8534373) on editing the built in DHCP configuration, you have to edit the `bootpd.plist` file manually to change things like the IP address, gateway, and subnets your Mac uses.

You can find the `bootpd.plist` in root directory of your startup disk. There is an alias to the **etc** folder the `bootpd.plist` file is in, but the full path is `your-startup-disk/private/etc`.

If double-click on a .plist file, it will probably open in TextEdit, which can be a drag. Xcode, if you have it installed, will display the .plist file with a table structure that is easy to see and edit, like this:

[image: example of a bootpd.plist file opened in Xcode]

If you don't have Xcode installed or do not want to install it, I suggest using [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/download.html) (it has a free 30 day trial) because it will color the xml formatting in the `bootpd.plist` file to make things easy to find and change, like this:

[image: example of a bootpd.plist file opened in BBEdit]

Of course editing from the Terminal is always an option too: `sudo vi /etc/bootpd.plist`.

After you make changes to the `bootpd.plist` file, you should stop the service from the Terminal:

```
sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist
```

and to start it:

```
sudo /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist
```

Also, both of these commands may vary slightly depending on your version of MacOS. These commands came from this link

*To disable the DHCP server*, you will have to find this line in the `bootpd.plist` file:

```
 <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
```

and just below it add `<false>` like this:

```
 <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
 <false/>
```

Reboot to test that the DHCP server is disabled.

Comment: I believe this is the answer. One note, on my another MacBook Pro, there is no `/private/etc/bootpd.plist` file, I suppose this is because that Mac has not enabled network sharing.

Comment: @zerox - Yes, that's right. If you enable Internet Sharing, MacOS will add the `bootps.plist` file into `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and the `bootpd.plist` in `/private/etc`.

Comment: Every time I disable and enable the "network sharing" in the "Sharing" section of system preferences, the `bootpd.plist` file is just rewritten to the vanilla state: https://pastebin.com/XX6zXeUB.

And my `bootpd.plist` file's `<key>dhcp_enabled</key>` has a value of `<array>`, which is a list of interfaces rather than a boolean value. If I change that `<array>` into `<false/>`, and use `launchctl` to do reloading, the file becomes like this: [updated `bootpd.plist`](https://pastebin.com/wL0iweQX), not sure if this is actually effective.

Comment: My SIP is disabled and that might explain why my `bootpd.plist` does not get overwritten. You can follow the instructions here to disable yours if it is not already disabled: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection